# How to pass interface of struct type by reference in golang?

Tags: pointers, go

I need to pass an interface of a struct type by reference as shown below. Since, I can't use pointers of interface to struct type variables, how should I change the below code to modify `te` value to `10`?.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func another(te *interface{}) {
    *te = check{Val: 10}
}

func some(te *interface{}) {
    *te = check{Val: 20}
    another(te)
}

type check struct {
    Val int
}

func main() {
    a := check{Val: 100}
    p := &a
    fmt.Println(*p)
    some(p)
    fmt.Println(*p)
}
```

Thanks!

P.S I have read that passing pointers to interfaces is not a very good practice. Kindly let me know what could be a better way to handle it

Comment: Go has no notion of pass by reference.

Comment: @Volker: sorry for the misuse of the term but I hope you got my intention of the question

Comment: To do something similar to pass-by-reference in go you need to use pointers.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: could you provide an example. I have tried using pointers but wasn't succesful

Comment: Nope, sorry, I'm just reading off of the documentation. I've never used go. Every parameter in go is pass-by-value, but you can pass a pointer (by value).

Comment: Why would you need to pass a pointer to the interface? If you pass a pointer to your struct, and the struct implements the desired interface, then you would still have a pointer to the concrete object under the hood. The fact that you're trying to change that underlying object seems like you might not understand the purpose of an interface.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So you're using an interface, and you need some sort of guarantee that you can set the value of a member of the struct?  Sounds like you should make that guarantee part of the interface, so something like:

```golang
type Settable interface {
    SetVal(val int)
}

func (c *check) SetVal(val int) {
    c.Val = val
}

func some(te Settable) {
    te.SetVal(20)
}

type check struct {
    Val int
}

func main() {
    a := check{Val: 100}
    p := &a
    some(p)
    fmt.Println(*p)
}
```

Comment: Just as a clarifier: `some(a)` will not compile because `check` does not implement `Settable`. `some(&a)` will work because `*check` does implement `Settable`. And by the way, you may want to remove the `p` variable and use `some(&a)` and `fmt.Println(a)` to show that the function is actually changing `a` and not only `p`, as new gophers may think that you are changing `p` but not `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the below should work

```
func some(te interface{}) {
    switch te.(type) {
    case *check:
        *te.(*check) = check{Val: 20}
    }
}
```